# No es posible leer las propiedades de undefined

Tags: reactjs

alguien sabe por que presionar sobre el boton que ejecuta esta funcion, en consola me dice "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')" ---->

```
agregarFavoritos: (personaje) => {
                const store = getStore();
                const favorites = [...store.favorites];
                let mensaje = "";

                // Busca el índice del personaje en la lista de favoritos
                console.log(personaje);
                const index = favorites.findIndex((fav) => fav.name === personaje.name);

                // Si el personaje ya está en la lista, lo eliminamos
                if (index !== -1) {
                    favorites.splice(index, 1);
                    mensaje = `${personaje.name} fue eliminado de la lista de favoritos.`;
                } else {
                    favorites.push(personaje);
                    mensaje = `${personaje?.name} se agregó a la lista de favoritos.`;
                }

                setStore({
                    favorites,
                    mensaje,
                });
            },
```

Comment: El parámetro `personaje` que recibe la función `agregarFavoritos` es `undefined`, está claro el problema. En todo caso que efectivamente el parámetro pueda ser `undefined`, la solución es agregar signos de pregunta `?` antes de nombrar las propiedades: `personaje?.name`

Comment: `personaje.name` lo usas en 2 puntos en tu codigo, cual de los 2 da el error?

Comment: Ya quedo gentecita! Le añadi un ? al fav.name y me quedo fav?.name y anduvo. Gracias!